# How to map entities using hibernate and an oracle function

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to map a few entities based on the result of an oracle stored function that return a cursor.

My code looks like this:

```
this.getSession().createSQLQuery("{?=call my_pkg.my_func(:myPar1,:myPar2)}")
                .addEntity(MyTargetClass.class)
                .setParameter("myPar1",par1)
                .setParameter("myPar2",par2)
                .list();
```

With this code I get the following exception:

java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3

How can I tell Hibernate that the missing parameter is a cursor?

According to this [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/reference/en/html/querysql.html) it should be possible, but there's no sample code as to actually invoke the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the document that you link to,

> To use this query in Hibernate you need to map it via a named query.

So, create a named query, something like this:

```
<sql-query name="my_pkg_my_func_SP" callable="true">
    <return alias="..." class="MyTargetClass">
        <return-property name="..." column="..."/>
        ...
    </return>
    { ? = call my_pkg.my_func(:myPar1,:myPar2) }
</sql-query>
```

And call it using something like this:

```
final List<MyTargetClass> myTargetClassList =
    this.getSession().getNamedQuery("my_pkg_my_func_SP")
    .setParameter("myPar1", par1)
    .setParameter("myPar2", par2)
    .list();
```